# How to import variables from another script python 3

Tags: python-3.x

How can I import a variable from another script using `python 3`?

**Example:**

I have two scripts that we shall call `script_1.py` and `script_2.py`.

**script_1.py:**

```
class Calculate():
   def addition():
      a = 5
      b = 2
      c = a + b
```

**Q:** How can I use this second script (`script_2.py`) to print the variable `c` from the `script_1.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this since `c` is not a global variable and doesn't even seem to exist outside of `addition`. Even if it does exist outside of your class, then the `addition` method (which should either be `def addition(self)` or be declared with `@staticmethod` decorator by the way) won't change it since it's not declared as a global variable in it.

Script 1

```
class Calculate():
    @staticmethod
    def addition():
       a = 5
       b = 2
       c = a + b
       return c
```

Script 2

```
from script_1 import Calculate

print(Calculate().addition())
```

Will output the value of `c` (eg 7).

If you **need** a global variable (you almost certainly don't) :

Script 1

```
c = None

class Calculate():
    @staticmethod
    def addition():
       global c
       a = 5
       b = 2
       c = a + b
```

Script 2

```
from script_1 import c, Calculate

Calculate().addition()
print(c)
```

You really shouldn't do this. Global **variables** can lead to serious problems. Global **constants** however are usually ok.